# Intent filter for receiving intents

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have one question about android programming. I have an file explorer app and I want to implement various functions like open photos music etc. But in app itself, not sending intents to other apps! So, my question is, what intent filter I should use for "plugin" app for receiving "opening" intent ?

This is my code

```
public static void openFile(final Context context, final File target) {
    final String mime = MimeTypes.getMimeType(target);
    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (mime != null) {
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(target), mime);
    } else {
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(target), "*/*");
    }

    if (context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, 0).isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.cantopenfile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.cantopenfile) + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok let's assume you want to open an image from your own explorer
create a new Activity let's say ImageActivity, then you simply implement an ImageViewer inside your activity and from the calling Activity simply send an intent with an Extra Bundle containing your image Bytes

EDIT

SENDING ACTIVITY

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
            ImageView imageView =  findViewById(R.id.image).getDrawable();
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap image = imageView.getDrawingCache();
     Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putParcelable("imagebitmap", image);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving Activity ImageActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.getParcelable("imagebitmap");
                ImageView image =  findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp );
```

Comment: Yeah, but what should I write in that ImageActivity ? Please write some code.

Comment: Okay, going to try it. :)

Comment: Not working. Can you please adapt it to my code below ?